# Access Formik's values outside of component | React

Tags: reactjs, formik

### Some info

I am using Formik for my project and I have my setup looking like this:

```
|-MenuModal
|--MenuEdit
|---MenuEditForm
```

Where `MenuModal` is the parent to `MenuEdit` and `MenuEditForm`. The component `MenuEditForm` is responsible for returning the Formik form, but I am calling the submit in it's parent `MenuModal`, which laters runs the submit function in `MenuEdit` via React's refs. Messy? Yup!

### My problem

Right now I am trying to use state and callback functions to get the Formiks `values` from `MenuEditForm` to `MenuEdit`. But since I am not using Formiks own `onSubmit`:

```
    <Formik
        initialValues={menu}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={values => console.log('values', values)} // 'values' is undefined
        ...
```

My `values` will be undefined and I can't make my submit function go through.

So I wonder how I can access my `values` in `MenuEditForm` so I later can pass it up to `MenuEdit` and complete my submit function.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 56):

To access values outside of the formik component, you can do this with hooks:

```
      const formRef = useRef();

      return (
        <Formik
          ...
          innerRef={formRef}
        >
        ...
      </Formik>
```

Then, can access values using formRef.current.values anywhere outside of the component.

Comment: Any idea why the innerRef  prop is nowhere to be found in the docs?

Comment: @AbrahamL [can be found here](https://formik.org/docs/api/field#innerref)

Comment: @AbrahamL That's for `Field`.

Comment: This works, I can use `handleChange` in useEffect.

Answer (score 3):

Since formik passes value to onChangeText we can save it in useState for dynamic updates

```
  onChangeText={(value: string) => {
      handleChange('name')(value);
      setName(value);
  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (using older version of react 16.5) the "innerRef" prop does not exist so I used the regular "ref" and it worked.

Here an ex with class component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.formRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

Before using it you should check that the Formik class is accessible because it is null when the page is rendering :

```
getFormikValues = () => {
    const formikValues = this.formRef.current && this.formRef.current.state && 
    this.formRef.current.state.values
    return formikValues
}
```

or if you have a support for optional chaining

(see [More supported alternative to optional chaining in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863955/more-supported-alternative-to-optional-chaining-in-react))

just use:

```
   getFormikValues = () => {
      const formikValues = this.formRef.current?.state?.values
       return formikValues
   }

  doSomethingWithFormikValues = () => {
    const formikValues = this.getFormikValues()
    return
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      ref={this.formRef}
    >
    ...
  </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a function to receive the values from child component.

Eg:

*MenuModal:*

```js
const MenuModal = () => {
  const [values, setvalues] = useState();
  return (
    ...
      <MenuEdit values={values} onFormSubmit={(values) => setvalues(values)} />
    ...
  );
}
```

*MenuEdit:*

```js
const MenuEdit = ({values, onFormSubmit}) => {
    // do something with values
    return (
      ...
      <MenuEditForm onFormSubmit={onFormSubmit} />
      ...
    )
  ...  
}
```

*MenuEditForm:*

```js
const MenuEditForm = ({onFormSubmit}) => (
  ...
  <Formik
    initialValues={menu}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={values => onFormSubmit(values)}
  ...
)
```

Comment: What if you need access to the values before the form submits?