# More supported alternative to optional chaining in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

This code does not work because project is undefined on the initial page load:

```
const project = useSelector(state => state.project.projects[projectID]);
const projectTasks = useSelector(state => state.project.projects[projectID].tasks);
```

Using optional chaining solves this

```
const projectTasks = useSelector(state => state.project.projects[projectID]?.tasks);
```

However, I know that this feature was just added and is probably not widely supported.

What is a good alternative?

I came up with this code:

```
const project = useSelector(state => state.project.projects[ID]);
const projectTasks = project ? project.tasks : [];
```

But it does not work, as the project tasks are fetched AFTER the project is fetched. Therefore, the component never re-renderers for a change in `project.tasks`.

Comment: "However, I know that this feature was just added and is probably not widely supported." You're probably using a transpiler anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining makes accessing and extracting the deep chained properties of an object shorter, simpler, and enhances readability.
The support was added to chrome recently. It is available in Chrome version 80 onwards. Few browsers like IE don't support Optional Chaining at all.
([Other browser support list](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3F.))

- For supporting all the browsers, you would need to include the optional chaining babel plugin [@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining). It will handle all the transformations of optional chaining expression, making them expressions compatible with all browsers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They are looking for an alternative, not how to implement optional chaining in their project.

Comment: Optional chaining is a nice way of avoiding unnecessary conditional statements. The problem here is that all browser versions don't support it. The plugin solves the problem and provides support for all the browsers.