# How to get Formik values into useState()

Tags: reactjs, use-state, formik

In my form, I have a select input. When an item is selected I would like to store the value in a useState variable. But I am not sure how to access the Formik values outside of the form.

```
 <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="asset">
        <Form.Label>Select Asset</Form.Label>
        <Form.Select
          aria-label="Deslect asser to buy"
          name="asset"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.asset}
        >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
          <option value="ethereum">Ethereum</option>
          <option value="binancecoin">Binance Coin</option>
          <option value="tether">Tether </option>
          <option value="solana">Solana </option>
          <option value="binancecoin">Cardano</option>
          <option value="ripple">Ripple</option>
          <option value="polkadot">Polkadot</option>
          <option value="dogecoin">Dogecoin </option>
          <option value="avalanche-2">Avalanche</option>
        </Form.Select>
        {touched.asset && errors.asset ? (
          <div className="error">{errors.asset}</div>
        ) : null}
      </Form.Group>`enter code here`
```

Comment: DUplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364080/access-formiks-values-outside-of-component-react

Comment: Doesn't help :S